# task managment or To do chrome extension

Tags: gratis, chrome

I am looking for Task Management Chrome extension with features like :-

- Can work offline
- Add tasks easily
- Good user interface
- Save task history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing which meets all of your requirements.
If you ditch the "can work offline" requirement [Tooodledo](http://toodledo.net) comes in mind.

If you can't live without "can work offline" I would go with [MyLifeOrganized](http://mylifeorganized.net).
But it is not in the browser.